# How do I call a method which is in another class, when swiping up, down, left or right? Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, swipe

I have a Unity project that I started a couple of days ago. It is a simple 2D top down shooting game, which is aimed to be played on smartphone platforms.

I have a Shooting script, which basically has a method called Shoot1, which spawns in a bullet.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject BulletRedPrefab;
    public GameObject BulletGreenPrefab;
    public float bulletForce = 20f;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator Shoot1()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.00001f);
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(BulletRedPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.AddForce(firePoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

I also have the Swipe script which determines the direction of the swipe, etc.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool tap, swipeUp, swipeDown, swipeLeft, swipeRight;
    private bool isDraging = false;
    private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;
    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        tap = swipeUp = swipeDown = swipeLeft = swipeRight = false;
        if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
        {
            if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                isDraging = true;
                tap = true;
                startTouch = Input.touches[0].position;
            }
            else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
            {
                isDraging = false;
                Reset();
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            tap = true;
            isDraging = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isDraging = false;
            Reset();
        }

        swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;

        if (isDraging)
        {
            if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
                swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
        }

        if (swipeDelta.magnitude > 125)
        {
            float x = swipeDelta.x;
            float y = swipeDelta.y;
            if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
            {
                if (x < 0)
                    swipeLeft = true;
                else
                    swipeRight = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (y < 0)
                    swipeDown = true;
                else
                    swipeUp = true;
            }
            Reset();
        }
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        isDraging = false;
    }

    public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
    public bool SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
    public bool SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }
    public bool SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
    public bool SwipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
}
```

And I have the GestureDetector script which is aimed to shoot a bullet whenever the user swipes left, right, up or down. When I tried to make the player object (which is called robot) move via swiping, it worked. But when I try calling a method from another class with swiping, it's not working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GestrueDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Shooting other;
    public Swipe swipeControls;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        if (GameObject.Find("robot") != null)
        {
            if (swipeControls.SwipeLeft)
                desirePosition += Vector3.left;
            other.Shoot1();

            if (swipeControls.SwipeRight)
                desirePosition += Vector3.right;
            other.Shoot1();

            if (swipeControls.SwipeUp)
                desirePosition += Vector3.up;
            other.Shoot1();

            if (swipeControls.SwipeDown)
                desirePosition += Vector3.down;
            other.Shoot1();
        }
    }
}
```

I just started using unity this week, so I'm quite new to the software. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For coroutines you need to call this methods like this:

```
StartCoroutine(Shoot1());
```

I a little bit changed your classes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject BulletRedPrefab;
    public GameObject BulletGreenPrefab;
    public float bulletForce = 20f;

    void Start ()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
       StartCoroutine(Shoot1());
    }

    private IEnumerator Shoot1()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.00001f);
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(BulletRedPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        
        rb.AddForce(firePoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

And for GestrueDetector:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GestrueDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
public Shooting other;

public Swipe swipeControls;

   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
   private void Update()
    {

        if (GameObject.Find("robot") != null)
{
    
        if (swipeControls.SwipeLeft)
            desirePosition += Vector3.left;
              other.Shoot();    

        if (swipeControls.SwipeRight)
            desirePosition += Vector3.right;
              other.Shoot();

            if (swipeControls.SwipeUp)
            desirePosition += Vector3.up;
            other.Shoot();
                 

                  

            if (swipeControls.SwipeDown)
            desirePosition += Vector3.down;
            other.Shoot();
                  

                  


}
        }
    }
```

Just read more about how coroutines are working in Unity - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html

Comment: Thanks very much! Whenever I swipe left, right, up or down, the method is called! The only problem is that I built the project and exported it on my phone to test it (like I usually do), and swipe, the bullet gets spawned as I wish, but not while aiming. I wanted to be able to aim the robot with one finger, and swipe with the other to fire (it doesn't really matter where the user needs to swipe). Any idea on how to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Add control for aiming, maybe just make a joystick for aiming, and for swipe save the TouchId.

Separate and define touch which for aiming and which for shooting